# simple subselect

Tags: sql

Hi  Don't do a great deal of sql these days so struggling with a simple task

I have table-A, that has a field called table-B-ids, which looks like an array =1, 4, 5, etc.

And i have table-B, which has table-B-id as primary key

what i want to do is select from table-A and then get all records from table-B using table-B-ids maybe using a subselect

```
select fields 
from table-A 
where id=1 (select fields from table-B where table-B-id IN table-B-ids)
```

any help?

Comment: How are you storing an array in a field? What database is this?

Comment: Some example rows would help.  And which database are you using?

Comment: i'm noit storing an array in a field, but i will be using the data as an array,

Comment: Can you add exact table structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead, like this:

select A.[B-ids], B.* 
from [table-A] A
join [table-B] B on A.[B-ids]=B.[table-B-id]

Comment: IT is a bad answer. He has in B-ids string like '1, 2, 4', how can you make a join on 1 = '1, 2, 4' ?

Comment: Otto, read Roy's answer. He claims that B-ids are not stored as array inside field. So I assume that id's are stored as records (rows).

Comment: yes that's correct B-ids in table-A are id's from table-B, i need a way to retreive records from table-B using the B-d's field in table-A,

Comment: table-A Row: id=1| firsname=roy| lastname=adams| table-B-ids=1, 3, 2|  table-B Row: table-B-id = 1| info=info for B-id1 -- need to get result: roy adams - info for B-id1 , info for B-id 2, info for B-id3

Comment: @Roy: You said in the other comment that you were not storing an array in a field, but it now appears that you are. And that design actually breaks [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form "First normal form (Wikipedia)"), whereby a column must contain a single value only. Consider changing the design and using a mapping table instead (then the task will become simple indeed).